# How does one compute a time_t for the epoch in pure ISO C?

Tags: c, time, timezone

Using nothing but the C standard library (plain ISO C, no POSIX, and thus no assumption that `time_t` is represented in "seconds since the epoch"), what is the simplest way to get a `time_t` value corresponding to 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 **UTC**?

The UTC part is the key; otherwise, just using `mktime` on a properly initialized `struct tm` would trivially solve the problem.

Alternatively (this is actually the "point" of the question), how does one portably determine the number of POSIX seconds between a given `time_t` value, e.g. the current time obtained via `time(0)`, and the epoch? By "POSIX seconds" I mean the definition used in POSIX's "Seconds Since the Epoch" which does not use leap seconds. If this sounds too complicated, just go back to the question as originally stated in the first paragraph and assume the epoch is representable in `time_t`.

Comment: "would trivially solve the problem" -- assuming that time is representable by `time_t`, of course. Otherwise it trivially lets you know there is no solution :-)

Comment: OK, well let's assume that. The ultimate direction of this question is to get a 100% portable way of querying the current time as seconds since the epoch, so if the "standard" epoch can't be represented as `time_t`, the ultimate solution could use a different reference point and apply the difference at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an entry for a way to do it, "simplest" if nobody beats it:

- call `mktime` on a `struct tm` for `02 Jan 1970 00:00:00`
- call `mktime` on a `struct tm` for `31 Dec 1969 00:00:00`. This could reasonably return -1, in which case treat it as 0.
- Binary search between the two for a value of `time_t` that, when passed to `gmtime`, results in `01 Jan 1970 00:00:00`

Assumes that no local time is ever more than 24 hours different from UTC, which I'm pretty sure is a fact. We could widen the boundaries if necessary, in extremis we could search between `0` and `time(0)`.

The binary search could be improved on, for example by interpolation. But who knows, maybe some crazy time zone (or broken tzinfo data) could cause a daylight savings change in December/January. I doubt that happened for any real time zone. But it's not forbidden by the C standard, only by common sense.

If it wasn't for that, I think we could calculate based on `gmtime(mktime(01 Jan))` (to get the time zone) and a comparison of `01 Jan 1970 00:00:00` vs `01 Jan 1970 00:00:01` (to get the precision of `time_t`).

Comment: +1 very clever. However I don't think you can binary search a `time_t` because it does not have numerical properties; it could just be a buffer of N bits representing a time in some complex way, e.g. using the bits of a `double` as a 64-bit integer on a C89 implementation.

Comment: @R.. "The types declared are `size_t` (described in 7.17); `clock_t` and `time_t` which are arithmetic types capable of representing times" ([C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) 7.23.1). Seems like it has numerical properties to me. (And the same language is present in C89 as well).

Comment: Just the fact that it's an arithmetic type doesn't mean that the order relation on the numerical type has anything to do with ordering between times. In other words you could have `x<y` but `difftime(x,y)>0`. Nowhere is it specified that lower numeric values of `time_t` represent earlier times.

Comment: Oh right, I see what you mean. The text for `difftime` says, "The difftime function computes the difference between twocalendar times: `time1 - time0`". But you can probably argue that's a hypothetical `-`. It may or may not be intended to indicate subtraction of the arithmetic type, and regardless of what it intends it may or may not actually require that.

Comment: It seems to me that the only purpose of the `difftime` function is to account for the possibility that direct subtraction of `time_t` values is not valid. Otherwise you could just subtract them yourself (and possibly have to scale the result).

Comment: @R..: I thought the purpose of difftime was that you don't know how to scale the result yourself (at least, not without calling gmtime twice and comparing the results). Anyway, if `time1 - time0` is not a C expression that represents the difference in times (in the units of `time_t`) then I think it's a defect in the standard to present it as pseudo-code that means the difference in times.

Comment: Actually, I think you might be able to binary search between two `time_t` values portably by using `difftime` to compute the difference them applying half that to the `tm_sec` member of a `struct tm`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is rather fundamental: ISO C punts on time zones almost entirely, simply providing `mktime()` and the `localtime()` and `gmtime()` conversions, with a hook for daylight savings. (*They implement, you decide.*)

So there seems like only two things you can do:

1. assume that `time_t` is seconds-since-epoch UTC and use `gmtime()` to verify that, and panic or alert if it ever fails; *or*
2. rely on a more comprehensive standard than ISO C

Comment: It doesn't punt *entirely* though; the one interface it gives you to UTC is the `gmtime` function, which should be enough to derive the result in a fully portable way.

Comment: That's the annoying thing: there's no standard function to compute the inverse of `gmtime` like there is for `localtime`. I don't see that this absence grants any implementation freedom at all, just one less function to write.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Choose any `time_t` (the current time will work just fine) as a reference point; call it `t0`.

Step 2: Call `gmtime` on `t0` and compute the difference between the result and the epoch in a broken-down `struct tm` form.

Step 3: Call `localtime` on `t0` and apply the broken-down difference from step 2 to the resulting `struct tm`. Then call `mktime` on it to get back a `time_t`.

The result should be a `time_t` representing the epoch.

My first attempt to implement this had problems when the local time offsets are not constant over time, for example in localities where daylight time has been added or abandoned or which switched from observing one zone to another. This seems to be because the data in the `struct tm` on which the time zone information is based gets changed. Here is the original implementation, with its problems:

```
time_t get_epoch(time_t t0)
{
    struct tm gmt = *gmtime(&t0);
    struct tm tmp = *localtime(&t0);
    tmp.tm_sec -= gmt.tm_sec;
    tmp.tm_min -= gmt.tm_min;
    tmp.tm_hour -= gmt.tm_hour;
    tmp.tm_mday -= gmt.tm_mday-1;
    tmp.tm_mon -= gmt.tm_mon;
    tmp.tm_year -= gmt.tm_year-70;
    return mktime(&tmp);
}
```

and an improved version, where `posix_time` is a function to compute the seconds since the epoch for a given `struct tm` using the POSIX formulae (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15), with additional work to handle years before 1970, etc. if needed:

```
time_t get_epoch(time_t t0)
{
    struct tm gmt = *gmtime(&t0);
    struct tm tmp = *localtime(&t0);
    long long offset = posix_time(&gmt);
    while (offset > INT_MAX) {
        offset -= INT_MAX;
        tmp.tm_sec -= INT_MAX;
        mktime(&tmp);
    }
    while (offset < -INT_MAX+61) {
        offset -= -INT_MAX+61;
        tmp.tm_sec -= -INT_MAX+61;
        mktime(&tmp);
    }
    tmp.tm_sec -= offset;
    return mktime(&tmp);
}
```

For C89 compatibility, `long long` would have to be dropped and the number of `mktime` calls needed increases dramatically; `offset` could not be computed as a single value, but a loop would be needed to call `mktime` multiple times per year.

Comment: Something odd. I get a different answer for `3600*24*668` than for `3600*24*669`. The timestamp corresponds to 31st October 1971 on which (according to my Python installation, it's quicker than writing the C code) the clocks changed in my timezone. No such disparity occurs in 1970. `(unsigned long long)get_epoch(time(0))` is -3600. Is this just me? This is using gcc on Cygwin, not some system with a funny epoch.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I think it's wrong to adjust the year, maybe the month too. I would just apply the whole difference in seconds but I'm worried about overflow since the number of seconds could overflow `int`.

Comment: I guess I could cheat and just call `mktime` in a loop, making sure not to overflow the seconds on each iteration..

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if `t0` is a time in which Daylight Saving Time is active? (Or, more precisely, if DST at the epoch and DST at `t0` don't match; I suppose you might have DST in January in the southern hemisphere.) You could *probably* avoid this by picking January 1 of some year for `t0` -- unless the local time zone either added or dropped DST altogether some time between the epoch and `t0`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The `struct tm` contains a `tm_isdst` member which `mktime` has to honor.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* Perhaps the following implementation of the non-standard `timegm` would meet the non-POSIX requirements of the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t my_timegm(struct tm *tm) {
   time_t t, g;
   double dt; // seconds
   struct tm *gm;
   t = mktime(tm);
   gm = gmtime(&t);
   gm->tm_isdst = 0;
   g = mktime(gm);
   dt = difftime(t, g);
   if (dt >= 0) {
      tm->tm_sec += fmod(dt, 60); // needed to handle 16-bit ints
      tm->tm_min += dt / 60;
   }
   else {
      tm->tm_sec -= fmod(-dt, 60);
      tm->tm_min -= -dt / 60;
   }
   return mktime(tm);
}

int main(void) { // prints time_t for 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
   struct tm start;
   memset(&start, 0, sizeof start);
   start.tm_year = 70; // = 1970
   start.tm_mday = 1;  // = 1st
   printf("%ld\n" my_timegm(&start)); // gives 0 on any POSIX system
   return 0;
}
```

This assumes `mktime` will, as per the Linux man page, act so that `structure members .. outside their valid interval ... will be normalized`, or at least ensure something sensible is returned. I don't know whether plain ISO C guarantees this.

My initial version of `my_timegm` was from http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2002-November/025571.html, and is credited there to Beeman, Baushke, Sabol, and Zawinski:

```
time_t my_timegm(struct tm *tm) {
   time_t t, g;
   struct tm *gm;
   t = mktime(tm);
   if (t == -1) { // perhaps needed for DST changeover?
      tm->tm_hour--;
      if ((t = mktime(tm)) != -1)
         t += 3600;
   }
   gm = gmtime(&t);
   gm->tm_isdst = 0;
   g = mktime(gm);
   if (g == -1) {
      gm->tm_hour--;
      if ((g = mktime(gm)) != -1)
         g += 3600;
   }
   return (t == -1 || g == -1) ? -1 : t - (g - t); // or difftime
}
```

I'm still thinking about the need for the code: `tm->tm_hour--`, etc.

Comment: It's performing arithmetic in units of seconds on `time_t`, so it's definitely not plain portable C.

Comment: *Yet another edit:* In the real world, `fmod(dt, 60)` is always zero, so two lines could be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

My previous approach had too many problems stemming from ambiguity about how `mktime` resolves denormalized time representations for me to be comfortable with it, so I'm going to try merging the idea with Steve Jessop's guessing/search idea for a better approach:

1. Initialize a `struct tm` object `tm0` to the calendar time of the epoch.
2. Call `mktime` on `tm0`. This will result in its being interpreted as local time, however, so the result will not be the desired answer. Call this `time_t` value `t0`.
3. Apply `gmtime` to `t0` to convert it to a broken-down universal time. It should differ from the desired epoch by less than 24 hours (actually, at most 12).
4. Adjust `tm0` by the difference and return to step 2. If step 3 gives the right broken-down universal time epoch, we are finished. Otherwise, repeat steps 2-4 (should not be necessary).

In code,

```
time_t get_epoch()
{
        struct tm tm0 = { .tm_year = 70, .tm_mday = 1 }, gmt;
        time_t t0;
        for (;;) {
                t0 = mktime(&tm0);
                gmt = *gmtime(&t0);
                if (!gmt.tm_sec && !gmt.tm_min && !gmt.tm_hour &&
                        !gmt.tm_yday && gmt.tm_year==70) return t0;
                tm0.tm_sec -= gmt.tm_sec;
                tm0.tm_min -= gmt.tm_min;
                tm0.tm_hour -= gmt.tm_hour;
                tm0.tm_mday -= gmt.tm_mday-1;
                tm0.tm_mon -= gmt.tm_mon;
                tm0.tm_year -= gmt.tm_year-70;
        }
}
```